# Why Class is Serialized Even Without NSCoding Protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following class:

## import

```
@interface Person : NSObject
{

}

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *lastName; 

@end

@implementation Person

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];

    self.firstName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"firstName"];
    self.lastName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"lastName"];

    return self;

}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:self.firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
    [coder encodeObject:self.lastName forKey:@"lastName"];
}

@end
```

I can still serialize this class without conforming the NSCoding protocol. The following code works. My question is why?

```
 // create a person
    Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
    person.firstName = @"John";
    person.lastName = @"Doe";

    NSData *personData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:person];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of `NSCoding` is

```
@protocol NSCoding

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder; // NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER

@end
```

Which means you class conforms it - you have implemented those methods. The only thing you haven't done is to declare that you implemented the protocol, which could lead to some warnings (or compile errors, just to prevent you from crashes), but generally you are good to go. Additionally you can do an experiment if `+conformsToProtocol:` returns YES, even thou you haven't declared it.

**Edit**: `Objective-C` is not a strongly typed language so you have the freedom to do things like that and it will work. One example is what you have done: implemented the protocol, but haven't declared so - and it works or you can declare that you are implementing the protocol, but don't actually implement those methods - then except for the warning you will get during compilation, your code will crash. In `Swift`, which is a strongly typed, you can't get into situation like that.